# Afinal PhoneGap (Apache Cordova) realmente compila as aplicações em PURO código nativo?

Tags: mobile, apache-cordova

O PhoneGap (Apache Cordova) realmente compila as aplicações em PURO código nativo ou ele atua como uma camada entre um browser e o S.O. do celular? Quais das duas opções abaixo é a mais correta?

Já ouvi falar que ele é apenas um browser com sua aplicação, tudo isso encapsulado (compilado) em uma aplicação nativa que vai apenas abrir esse digamos "mini-browser" com sua aplicação HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript, é verdade isso?

Ou o PhoneGap realmente transforma o código (HTML5 + CSS + JavaScript) produzido nele em código nativo de cada S.O. (acessando a API sem intermediários)?

Comment: A app nativa que ele gera é basicamente um browser. O código html/css/js roda nesse "browser".

Comment: Como gerou algumas dúvidas, editei para tentar facilitar o entendimento. Se não deu melhor entendimento para sua intenção, favor reverter ou reeditar.

Answer (score 8):

O PhoneGap produz um aplicativo estático composto de uma webview nativa e código para expor as funcionalidades de cada sistema para uma API em javascript. Seu código em HTML/CSS/JS será empacotado sem alterações significativas junto com o sistema nativo do PhoneGap e será executado como qualquer outra página da web, mas offline e com acesso às funções nativas. A engine que de fato executará o seu JavaScript depende de cada plataforma.

Sessão [*Overview*](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview) da documentação:

> The application itself is implemented as a web page, named index.html by default, that references whatever CSS, JavaScript, images, media files, or other resources are necessary for it to run. The app executes as a WebView within the native application wrapper, which you distribute to app stores. For the web app to interact with various device features the way native apps do, it must also reference a cordova.js file, which provides API bindings.

Tradução livre:

> O aplicativo é implementado como uma página de web, nomeada *index.html* por padrão, que referencia qualquer arquivo CSS, JavaScript, de imagem, multimídia, ou qualquer outro recurso necessário para que este funcione. O app executa como um *WebView* dentro do encapsulamento da aplicação nativa, a qual você distribui para as lojas de aplicativos. Para que o aplicativo de web interaja com as diversas funcionalidades do dispositivo da mesma forma que aplicações nativas fazem, ele deve também referenciar o arquivo *cordova.js*, que provém as conexões com a API.

Comment: Eu não votei down, até porque sua resposta está correta se excluir as primeiras palavras. O que está escrito, inclusive na sua resposta é que a **sua** aplicação não será nativa. E foi isso que foi perguntado, pelo menos foi essa a minha interpretação. O fato de ter um "interpretador", este sim ser nativo, é irrelevante.

Comment: Não entendi em que ponto está errado. A parte nativa seria estática no sentido de que ela não faz nada e funciona apenas como plano de fundo para o aplicativo propriamente dito, em js/html. O "Sim" foi em resposta ao "é verdade isso[?]".

Comment: A minha interpretação da pergunta foi outra. Entendi que ele quer saber se o html/css/js vai desaparecer e dar lugar a código de máquina nativo ou alguma outra forma intermediária p/ o S.O.. De fato ele pergunta de duas formas, que dá margem a ambiguidade. Eu li seu sim como, "Sim, o PhoneGap realmente compila as aplicações em PURO código nativo" e as aplicações continuarão sendo html/css/js interpretados (ou *jittados*, não conheço a tecnologia) por um host que é nativo.

Comment: Editei para deixar mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

A aplicação continuará a ser uma aplicação feita em `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS`, que após o `build`, será encapsulada em um app, porém rodando como se fosse uma `webview`, dependendo do device/plataforma que, com o cordova, irá disponibilizar os recursos para acessar algumas funcionalidades nativas.